# Параллельные запросы с разных IP

Tags: python, парсер, proxy, распараллеливание

Условно имеется 5 прокси  и 50 ссылок. 
Как сделать так, чтобы с каждого прокси параллельно был произведен парсинг ссылок по 10 для каждого. 
подскажите, какие библиотеки может быть использовать

Comment: Ип проще управлять на уровне прокси

Comment: Да, я неправильно выразилась. Исправила вопрос

Comment: Так вообще проблем нет)

Comment: тогда подскажите как, потому что у меня они есть (